# Find difference between two list and print their position and value in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the difference between two lists, but I would also like to know the position of the diff items.

My script isn't producing the results I want.

For example:

Here are the lists.

```
lst1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'plant', 'book', 'lamp']
lst2 = ['dog', 'mouse', 'plant', 'sock', 'lamp']
```

Here I am getting the position and value.

```
new_lst1 = [f"{i}, {v}" for i, v in enumerate(lst1)]
new_lst2 = [f"{i}, {v}" for i, v in enumerate(lst2)]
```

Then I want to find the difference between the two new lists.

```
def Diff(new_lst1, new_lst2):
    (list(set(new_lst1) - set(new_lst2)))
```

Afterwards, I want to print the results.

```
print(new_lst1)
```

However, I'm getting:

```
['0, dog', '1, cat', '2, plant', '3, book', '4, lamp']
```

Sorry for the long explanation!

Comment: `[(i, (v1, v2)) for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(zip(lst1, lst2)) if v1 != v2]` or some variant depending on the exact output format you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split `new_lst1`, but left `new_lst2` intact.  First of all, this gets a run-time error, not the output you mention.  If it did work, it gives you semantically incompatible elements to compare.  Get rid of the `split`:

```
def Diff(new_lst1, new_lst2):
    return list(set(new_lst1) - set(new_lst2))

# Afterwards, I want to print the results.
print(Diff(new_lst1, new_lst2))
```

Output:

```
['1, cat', '3, book']
```

You now have the correct information; format to taste.

Comment: Apologies for the mix-up, but thank you for the solution. This worked great!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for the [`symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) of these lists:

```
>>> set(enumerate(lst1)) ^ set(enumerate(lst2))
{(1, 'mouse'), (1, 'cat'), (3, 'book'), (3, 'sock')}
```

Unless you're only looking for just the positions:

```
>>> [i for i, word in enumerate(lst1) if lst2[i] != word]
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Subject to the restriction of the elements needing to be hashable, the symmetric differences is a neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the following code into a function if you would like but this should accomplish what you're trying. Remember the first item in the list starts at 0 in python. So when it says difference at 1, it means the second item.

```
lst1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'plant', 'book', 'lamp']
lst2 = ['dog', 'mouse', 'plant', 'sock', 'lamp']
varying_pos = []

for index, item in enumerate(lst1):
   if item != lst2[index]:
      message = str(index) + ', ' + item
      varying_pos.append(message)

print("The 2 lists vary at position:")

for value in varying_pos:
    print(value)
```